# Is there a safety rating for the other drivers in collisions?

Tags: safety

Does a safety rating (or any type of metric or statistic) exist that describes how safe a car is for other drivers (in other vehicles) involved in the collision?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure I understand your question. They will be as safe as their vehicle is created to be, therefore their safety rating will be dependent upon their vehicle and not yours. Their safety rating would be just as available as your safety rating.

Comment: Understood. In that case, maybe I am not looking for the safety rating, but a different statistic all together.  For example, a heavy SUV may be safe for its passengers, but more lethal for other vehicles, especially in high speed collisions.  Maybe the opposite would be a small economy car, which is potentially not very safe for its passengers, but rarerly lethal to the passengers in the other cars in a collision.  Maybe this "inverse safety rating" doesn't exist?

Comment: When vehicles are tested here in the States to get the safety rating, how they are tested is usually against a solid, immovable object. Different tests they run are head on as well as offset crashes (among others). I'm not seeing as how the information for this type of testing would be any different than for what occurs in the wild. It is the reason they do this testing in the first place and shouldn't negate the differences in vehicle sizes.

Comment: The days of cars with bumpers so solid that they used the other vehicle as the crumple zone ended in the 1970s or 80s.  Such a statistic now would be pontless.

Comment: Thank you both for the info!

Comment: I do not know the name of the statistic or the rating, but there are tests for how much injury a car causes to a pedestrian, and that has influenced some aspects of bumper, hood and front glass design. Maybe reading about that leads to some useful terminology to better search what you are looking for.